# MVC Architecture Understanding

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, model-view-controller

With all the tutorial out there, I managed to make a view displayed by a controller. However, I don't understand how do I allow the user to navigate through the site with MVC. Every request to the server must go through the controller? If every request must go through the controller, how am I supposed to let the controller define the type of response it should forward the request to.

Edit: I'm doing a school project which required me to convert my current not reusable code to MVC pattern but I'm not understanding the navigation part of different views. How to get from one view to another view. For example, the navbar  element should point to the controller or the view?

Comment: What do you mean by "define the type of response"?

Comment: Hey @Ophitect You may want to see [**Why should I use an MVC pattern?**](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/105352/why-should-i-use-an-mvc-pattern);

Comment: Let's say I defined my login controller, the login controller processed the login form and redirect the user to a view, either success or error.

View 1 is success.jsp
View 2 is product.jsp

I'm in View 1 now. How am I supposed to navigate to view 2?

Comment: @Ophitect you just use a link with a url expected by another controller...the controller comes first, its jobs is do whatever you nerd To do and redirect you To a view..

Comment: If by navigation you mean navigation via hyperlinks, then the answer has little to do with MVC. Once the page is served, the request is over. Web MVC is somewhat different from regular MVC where you respond to events by modifying the state of the view (the view and controller layers in web MVC are stateless most of the time). If you want to redirect the user, that should happen in the controller, not in the view. The view is  only responsible for how the output will look like (in theory).

Comment: Let say I mapped my controller ProductController to /ViewProduct, I use /ViewProduct ?

Comment: Each request(almost) should go through controller. In your example if you want to go to view 2 you should put some link (or button) in view 1 with a specific url pattern that when you hit the link(button) it goes to a controller method that forward(or redirect) you to another view

Comment: Exactly @Ophitect...

Answer (score 0):

The controller comes first, it comunicate with the model and send you to the view you want.

So, for what you need, in the view, just put some link with the url mapped in the controller you want...

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is that all actions "point" to the controller with a parameter telling it what the action is supposed to be, together with any other necessary parameters.

Suppose you have a simple registration form. You may have the following two actions: showRegistration and Register. MVC is not specific to the web, but I will provide the examples in that context (based on your comments). These two actions will point to your controller (say index.jsp) with URLs like this: /index.jsp?act=showRegistration and /index.jsp?act=Register.

Your controller will then have different logic for the different actions (you can do it in many ways yourself, or use some framework which does this switching logic for you). At the end of the day the logic in the controller will boil down to something like this:

```
if showRegistration:
    model.getCountries //to populate a dropdown maybe
    view.showRegistrationForm
if Register:
    model.validateRegistrationForm
    if not valid
        view.showRegistrationNotValid
    else 
        model.createUser
        if userCreated
            view.showSuccess
        else
            view.showCouldNotCreate
```

The idea is that the Controller contructs the full action using reusable model and view components. You can use the same `model.getCountries` in many different places, thus reusing the logic of retrieving a country list.

In practice, it requires a nontrivial effort to generalize the model and view actions. I've seen many projects decent into a chaos of hundreds of components created for a single purpose and used only once, and many components which are essentially duplicates because the developer did not know a similar one already exists, or needed slightly different logic and did not want to bother modifying the old code.